# Ctype has no attribute error found in the code

Tags: python, compiler-errors, ctypes

In this following code

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f"Void - Session: {username})"
```

I'm getting ctype has no attribute error.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? This is a windows specific call.

Comment: You probably just mis-typed it, just like you mistyped it in the question.  PLEASE, provide a full, working example that you have verified. Cut and paste that EXACT example code into this question. It's just a couple lines of code. Show the complete error message, not a paraphrase. It will say what attribute it couldn't find.  Otherwise, you get answers that just guess, which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the module `ctypes` has no variable, method, or object in it named `windll`. From the name of the variable, I assume that this code is designed for Windows. Check that you are not running Linux or MacOS. As well, it might be a simple misspelling or typo. Try running `dir(ctypes)` in the Python console to see if `windll` is really in there.